# Set TextField width in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

How I can set the width of a `TextField` in JavaFX?

```
TextField userTextField = new TextField();
```

I tried this:

```
TextField userTextField = new TextField();
userTextField.setPrefWidth(80);
```

But I don't see any change.

Comment: it depends on layout manager. Try setting `setMinWidth/setMaxWidth` as well

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Works pretty fine:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextFieldWidthApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TextField userTextField = new TextField();
        userTextField.setPrefWidth(800);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(userTextField));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just set this methods after you create the TextField:

```java
TextField myTf = new TextField();
myTf.setPrefWidth(80);
myTf.setMaxWidth(80);
```

Comment: Please make sure to add an explanation to your answer. It helps future readers on understanding what you are suggesting.

Comment: For anyone new wondering you can just do 
`TextField tf = new TextField();
tf.setMaxWidth(80);`
without the need to set the prefered width

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (that's how I landed on this page) and I fixed it by putting the textfield in a HBox. The problem might occur if the texfield is just put in a parent component alone where the siblings are layout managers. For example, putting it in a GridLayout alongside a VBox or HBox or a child GridLayout. Here is the code that did it;

```
HBox hbForTextField = new HBox();
TextField sample = new TextField();
sample.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);//Align text to center
sample.setPrefWidth(120);//Set width

//Add the texfield to the HBox
hbForTextField.getChildren().addAll(generatedPassword);
```

You can then add the HBox to the root or other parent layout manager.